# Linux Kernel API to get struct device from platform driver

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I'm wondering if there's a kernel API that allows one to obtain a `struct device` based on a few parameters. I'm using mainline kernel, version 3.3.

Here's the situation:
I have registered platform device `A` and set some driver data associated with A. There are multiple instances of `A` with different ID's, so A(1), A(2), A(3)...

Now, I am registering platform device `B`. The driver for `B` needs to own a specific instance of a `struct device` associated with `A(1)` or `A(2)` or 
`A(3)`...

So think of it like `B` owning `A(n)` in some way. One way that I could accomplish this is by having the `A` driver have a global `struct device` array that keeps track of all registered devices. However, with something as generic as platform drivers I'm wondering if the kernel supplies an API to obtain this based on a few parameters such as `platform driver` `name` and associated `id`.

Thanks!

Comment: For now on the only way is to have parent-child relationship between devices. There is one exception when the device is Multi Functional, in which case the MFD framework would be helpful. From your question is not clear what kind of relationship the devices (A and B) have.

Comment: I would say that an MFD driver would not be an appropriate model of my situation. I will most likely follow Federico's answer and create my own search method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that it exists. Actually I do not see what parameters can be used to select a `struct device` instance.

I think that you have to implement your own search method in the A driver.
In the A driver you keep track (global variable) of all instances.

Export from driver A a function `find_instance(<parameters>)` and use it in driver B.

If I remember well something similar is in place in the V4L2 framework in order to find I2C devices.

Comment: If it's device tree or ACPI based platform there is no need to do such as you can provide such dependency in the table. Harder case is run-time dependencies. I'm not sure what topic starter would like exactly to do.

Comment: of course, but if this is the case I hope he knows that it is already done in the device tree :) But I think that this is not the case because he is using kernel 3.3 (device tree is static) and he said that he registers devices later.

Comment: Federico is correct. Unfortunately I'm "stuck" with 3.3 and the static tree. I solved the problem by creating my own a_get and a_put functions in driver A, similar to something like clk_get or clk_put, but for struct device. Thanks